# GCC command to exclude a flag from -Wall?

Tags: gcc

Is it possible when compiling in GCC to include the **-Wall** flag but then exclude a single flag from that subset, such as **-Wattributes**? Alternately one could include all the warning flags but -Wattributes but I figured there must be a much cleaner way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible, just prefix the warning name with `no-`, like in

```
-Wno-attributes
```

This is generic for just about all boolean flags, not only warnings.